# Extra precision for floatval in php

Tags: php, floating-point, precision, numberformatter

I am running a piece of code to convert a string to a float on localhost ie, wamp server

```
$row['lat'] = floatval($row['lat']);
// Output :  15.2904195  <-- preferred format
```

The same code when run on an online server gives

```
15.2904195000000004966977940057404339313507080078125
```

I do not want this kind of precision, I prefer the number I receive when on localhost, why exactly do the outputs vary like this, how do I change it?

I have tried `number_format()` it works but it returns a string, I want a number to be returned not a string.

Comment: if `number_format()` works then again convert it into float value `(float) number_format ()`

Comment: Can you not use round http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php

Comment: @VipulSolanki tried and didn't work, still getting the huge number

Comment: @Lee tried and didn't work, huge number again

Comment: I expect the issue is that PHP is using binary floating-point. In binary floating-point, 15.2904195 cannot be represented exactly. Your local host may be showing you “15.2904195” while the online server shows “15.2904195000000004966977940057404339313507080078125”, but they have exactly the same value in memory; only the display is different. If this is so, you will not be able to store 15.2904195 in binary floating-point; it is mathematically impossible. All you can do is control the display or use a different format (e.g., store the number as a string).

Comment: @EricPostpischil it seems like that is probably what's happening, have resorted to storing it as a string now and converting it later to a number when required.